# trying to make php understand login as admin

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, admin

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'connection.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$user_id = $_POST ['user_id'];


$query = "SELECT *  FROM Register WHERE username= '$username' AND  Password = '$password' AND user_id= '$user_id' ";

 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or exit("Error in the query: $query. " .   mysqli_error());

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);



 if ($row ) {
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 echo '' . $username . '';
 &&  ($row ) {
 $_SESSION['user_id'] = 1;
 header('Location: AdminPage.php');
 }


 else if ($row ) {
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 echo '' . $username . '';``
 header('location:Login.php');
  && ($row ) {
 $_SESSION['user_id'] = > 1;
 header('Location: ProtectedPage.php');
  }
  else {

 $_SESSION['error'] = 'User not recognised';
   echo 'user not recognised';
  header('location:Login.php');

 }
```

im trying to make my php understand that if the user_id equals 1 then your an admin but i keep getting loads of errors and i know im vulnerable to SQL injection it isn't for live internet website which is why its vulnerable

Comment: You can't begin a statement with `&&`. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: im trying to make it understand if the username is correct and his user id = 1 then there treated as an admin and redirected to the AdminPage

Comment: But what is `&& ($row)` supposed to mean? It's not valid PHP syntax.

Comment: its the AND sign so that it recognises i need the username && user id, or do i not need an && statement within an if statement

Comment: if you want to seperate admin users from normal users then it will better idea to crate an extra field in the 'register' table with the flag true or false (0,or 1) and then when you get the output of the query then check against that field. if true then sent to protected page else where ever you like

Comment: `&&` is used as part of an expression, e.g. `if(something && somethingelse)`. You can't use it by itself. You can put another `if` there, like `if($user_id == 1)`.

Comment: i tried something like that i created a type field but it was causing difficulties within my php

Comment: Your `else if($row)` will never be executed, since it's the same condition as the previous `if`.

Comment: so for the if and && could you edit my code and give me an idea on how i may display this

Comment: I wonder why you get the `user_id` from `$_POST` -- do users really have to enter their numeric ID on the form, in addition to their username? Usually this is something you look up in the database, not get from the user.

Comment: so would this have to be changed from POST to GET as you are correct they do not enter it it is within the database to find

Comment: I'm saying it shouldn't come from the user at all. The form should just have username and password, not user_id. You get the user_id after the query with `$row['user_id']`.

Comment: right ive changed it and got rid of it from the top and query but login system will no longer log in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
include 'connection.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = "SELECT *  FROM Register 
          WHERE username= '" . $connection->real_escape_string($username) . "' 
            AND Password = '" . $connection->real_escape_string($password) . "'";

 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or exit("Error in the query: $query. " .   mysqli_error());

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($row) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
    if ($row['user_id'] == 1) {
        header('Location: AdminPage.php');
    } else {
        header('Location: ProtectedPage.php');
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'User not recognised';
    echo 'user not recognised';
    header('location:Login.php');
}
```

In `AdminPage.php`, you should check that the user is an admin with:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['user_id'] == 1)
```

`ProtectedPage.php` just needs to check that the user is logged in:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
```

Comment: i'll give this a try mate and let you know what happens

Comment: with this code my whole login system fails and will not log me in

Comment: I've updated the answer to get the user_id from the database, and also escape the input data to protect against SQL injection (converting to prepared queries would be even better).

Comment: ah actually now im encountering the issue of even users can access my Adminpage once logged in i can show you my php for admin page at the top if you need to see it

Comment: session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
 
    echo '' . $username . '';
 
    $_SESSION["message"] = "You must be logged in to see this Protected Page.Please Login";
 
   header("Location: Login.php");
  
    }

Comment: Your admin page needs to check that `$_SESSION['user_id'] == 1`.

Comment: ok well ive edited my code so that it looks like this  if (isset($_SESSION['user_id] == 1)) { echo " .$username. "; } else header ("Location: Login.php); the only issue appearing atm is that the == is showing a syntax error

Comment: right I've tweaking it from the code you've given but im still coming back to same issue even with your code it will not allow Admin onto AdminPage but it will allow a user onto both Pages

Comment: It should work as I wrote it, you're probably not tweaking it correctly. You need to learn PHP better -- copying without understanding is not an effective way to program.

Comment: its orite ive just stuck to your code and got to try change it to prevent users from accessing Admin Page but should hopefully be able to do it myself thanks for all the help mate i appreciate it

Comment: hi, at first your code worked fine but for some reason now it does not redirect me or allow me to see either the protected or Admin page, could you help me out if i post code.